# Scala Spark, compare two DataFrames and select the value of another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes. What I want to do exactly is:

If the column ***Name*** is "P" then I have to select the column called ***FinalValue*** of the DF2 where the column ***id_1*** match the column ***Id_name*** of the DF2, otherwise I have to fill it with nulls.

For example, I have the following DataFrames (DF1 and DF2):

```
+--------+-------+-------+
|Name    | value | id_1  |
+- ------+-------+-------+
|P       |5      | being |      
|X       |1      | dose  |
|Z       |1      | yex   |

df2
+--------+------------+
|Id_name | FinalValue |
+- ------+------------+
|ash     | h32        |
|being   | c11        |
|dose    | g21        |
```

In this case the output should be:

```
+--------+-------+-------------+
|Name    | value | FinalValue  | 
+- ------+-------+-------------+
|P       |5      | c11         |      
|X       |1      | null        |
|Z       |1      | null        |
```

What I am trying is the following:

```
var df3 = df1.withColumn("FinalValue", when($"Name" === "P", df2.select(...)))
```

But as you can see, I don't know how to continue because if I select a column of the DF2 I can't select another of the DF1. How can I do this?

Maybe my explanation is not good enough, if you need more information or explanation, just tell me it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a left join, then mask the final value using `when`:

```
val df3 = df1.join(
    df2,
    df1("id_1") === df2("Id_name"),
    "left"
).select(
    df1.columns.dropRight(1).map(col) :+
    when($"Name" === "P", $"FinalValue").as("FinalValue")
    : _*
)

df3.show
+----+-----+----------+
|Name|value|FinalValue|
+----+-----+----------+
|   P|    5|       c11|
|   X|    1|      null|
|   Z|    1|      null|
+----+-----+----------+
```

Comment: This could work, but if the name of the join column is different in the two dataframes? how can I do it?

Comment: For example Name and N_id ?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question. Could you give a complete example please (e.g. edit your question to add some sample data)

Comment: My bad, everything is ok mck, I am going to test it :)

Comment: Hi mck! in this example I have a lot of columns, but in the select there are only two, if I want to chose all the columns, how could I do it?

Comment: @MLstudent  Do you mean all the columns in df1 except id_1? You can check my edited answer

Comment: I think this works. For real, I want to learn as you! I am just learning Spark but this answers help me a lot. What's dropRight and map do working together?

Comment: dropRight remove the last element from the list of column names. map converts each list element to a column object

Comment: :+ appends a column to the list of columns, and :_* expands the list to varargs.